# How to install Visual Studio Code on WSL2?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I want to use `Visual Studio Code` already installed on Windows for WSL2 (I use ubuntu app on Microsoft Store). When I `cd` into the directory to use and type `code .` then show an error message

> To use Visual Studio Code with the Windows Subsystem for Linux, please
> install Visual Studio Code in Windows and uninstall the Linux version
> in WSL. You can then use the `code` command in a WSL terminal just as
> you would in a normal command prompt.

I have installed `Remote - WSL` plugin on Visual Studio Code and it works but can't open Visual Studio Code on ubuntu app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem, the cause is same as in messeage:

> To use Visual Studio Code with the Windows Subsystem for Linux, please
> install Visual Studio Code in Windows and uninstall the Linux version
> in WSL. You can then use the `code` command in a WSL terminal just as
> you would in a normal command prompt.

I installed extra `Visual Studio Code` on ubuntu app (this is not necessary) so when i type `code .` the system will understand that I'm using `Visual Studio Code` already installed on ubuntu app
I uninstall `Visual Studio Code` on ubuntu app by

```
sudo dpkg --purge code
rm -rf ~/.vscode
```

Note: make sure that the default of wsl is now ubuntu app, otherwise use the following command:

```
wsl -s Ubuntu-20.04
```

[image]

Then I typed `code .` on ubuntu app it actually opened `Visual Studio Code` on Windows for me.

[image]

Thanks for Watching!

Comment: I would potentially argue that you should use VSCode inside WSL2 *instead* of running it from MSWindoze because some VSCode plugins like Databricks Connect V2 **may** be buggy on Windows. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but **sometimes** the GNU\Linux version of VSCode seems preferable.

Answer (score 1):

If you've just installed vscode in Windows, you'll likely need to logout/in before the environment changes will be picked up so that you can use `code` in wsl/Ubuntu.

Another gotcha to lookout for is that VSCode insiders is launched with `code-insiders` not `code`. If that's your scenario, then use the following to create a softlink named `code` that will call `code-insiders`.

`ln -s "$(which code-insiders)" ~/.local/bin/code`